# Trying to print numbers from 10-60

Tags: r

I am getting started with programming and just started learning R.

I am trying to print all numbers between 10-60 using a for loop in R. I wrote the following code. what is wrong with it?

```
Number <- function(x)

{
  res <- 0
  for(i in 10:60){
    print("The number is" res)
    res <- res + x[i]
  }
 #return(res)
}
Number(22)
```

Comment: The logic is not clear.  What do you expect as output.  You have a sequence of numbers from 10 to 60 and when you call 'x', is it going to print from 10:32?

Comment: Do you mean `for(i in 10:60) print(i)`? Or `print(10:60)`? Is using a `for` loop an exercise requirement? What do you expect the output to be when you execute `Number(22)`?

Comment: yes, I wish to use only one parameter and print all the values of (i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to directly use the loop below.

```
res <- 0
  for(i in 10:60){
    print(sprintf("The number is %s",i+1))
    res <- i + 1
  }
```

Comment: `sprintf("The number is %s",1:10)`,`paste("The number is",1:10)`

Comment: yeah, paste will do the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways lead to Rome, so this is another possible approach. I strongly recommend you to read these books: "The Pirate’s Guide to R" and "The Art of R Programming"

```
Number <- function(Start, End) {
      for(i in seq(Start, End)) {
         cat("The number is ", i, "\n")
      }
}
Number(Start = 10, End = 60)
```